# If $λ_i > 0, \forall i$, $A$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given that $A \in R^{n,n}$, $λ_i $ the eigenvalues and $x_i$ the eigenvectors ($x_i^Tx_j=δ_{ij}$).
I have to show that if $λ_i > 0, \forall i$, $A$ is positive definite. 
My idea is the following: Let $y \in R^{n}-\{0\}$, then we have to show that $y^{T}Ay >0$. The set $\{x_i\}$ is a basis of $R^{n}$ , so there are $c_i \in R$ so that $$y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_ix_i} \Rightarrow Ay=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_iAx_i} =\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_iλ_ix_i}.$$ So $$y^{T}Ay=y^{T}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_iλ_ix_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_iλ_iy^{T}x_i}.$$ At this point I got stuck... How can I continue? How can I conclude to something that is positive?

Comment: Expand the term $y^Tx_i$ i.e. expand $y$ in terms of $x_i's$

Comment: @voldemort Could you explain it further? I haven't really understood..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have written $y^TAy=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nc_i\lambda_iy^Tx_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nc_i^2\lambda_i\lambda_jx_j^Tx_i$.

Can you proceed from here?
(Hint: use the property that $x_j^Tx_i=0$)

Comment: Since $x_j^Tx_i=0, j \neq i$, that equals to $c_i^2 λ_iλ_i=c_i^2λ_i^2 >0$, right?

To find your equality did you use the following?
$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_iλ_iy^Tx_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_iλ_i( \sum_{j=1}^{n} {c_jx_j})^Tx_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{ c_iλ_i( \sum_{j=1}^{n} {x_j^T  c_j^T})x_i }= \sum_{i=1}^{n}{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} {c_iλ_ix_j^T  c_j^T x_i}}$?

Comment: since $c_i's$ are "numbers" $c_i^T=c_i$. The rest is as you described. Also note that $c_i$ and $\lambda_i$ being numbers, commute with all the $x_i's$

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your help!